# When I try to add an argument to one class I get a Typeerror for classes that inherint from another one

Tags: python, inheritance, typeerror

I've got this code and there are no errors in it:

```
class Weapon(object): #don't know if this has to inherit from (object)
    def __init__(self,weaponName):
        self.weaponName=weaponName

class Character(object):
    def __init__(self,name,weaponName):
        self.name=name
        self.weapon=Weapon(weaponName)

class NPC(Character):
    def __init__(self,name,weaponName):
        super().__init__(name,weaponName)

class Friendly(NPC):
    def __init__(self,name,weaponName):
        super().__init__(name,weaponName)


sword=Weapon('sword')
guard=NPC('Bob','sword')

print(guard.weapon.weaponName)
print(guard.name)
```

But when I try to add a damage attribute to the Weapon class:

```
class Weapon(object):
    def __init__(self,weaponName,weaponDamage):
        self.weaponName=weaponName
        self.weaponDamage=weaponDamage

class Character(object):
    def __init__(self,name,weaponName):
        self.name=name
        self.weapon=Weapon(weaponName)

class NPC(Character):
    def __init__(self,name,weaponName):
        super().__init__(name,weaponName)

class Friendly(NPC):
    def __init__(self,name,weaponName):
        super().__init__(name,weaponName)


sword=Weapon('sword',15)
guard=NPC('Bob','sword')

print(guard.weapon.weaponName)
print(guard.name)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python files\inheritance test.py", line 21, in <module>
guard=NPC('Bob','sword')
  File "D:\Python files\inheritance test.py", line 13, in __init__
super().__init__(name,weaponName)
  File "D:\Python files\inheritance test.py", line 9, in __init__
self.weapon=Weapon(weaponName)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'weaponDamage'
```

Why is that? I don't want to actually reference the weaponDamage anywhere in the Character initialization, I just wanna be able to use it in later functions like attack and such. If I have multiple weapons I would like to be able to say 'This instance of Friendly has x weapon' and from there it knows what the damage of the weapon is by looking at the x instance of the Weapon class.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Why is that?

You specified in `Weapon.__init__()` that it needs `weaponDamage` as an argument. If you construct an instance of `Weapon` anywhere, you need to provide the value of `weaponDamage`.

You can rectify the error by providing a default value for `weaponDamage` in `Weapon.__init_()`.

```
class Weapon(object):
    def __init__(self,weaponName,weaponDamage=0):
        self.weaponName=weaponName
        self.weaponDamage=weaponDamage
```

Answer (score 1):

From error message

```
File "D:\Python files\inheritance test.py", line 9, in __init__
self.weapon=Weapon(weaponName)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'weaponDamage'
```

This means you need to call `Weapon` constructor at `line 9` like this.

```
Weapon(arg1, arg2)
```

Because `Weapon` constructor exactly take 2 argument.

**comment:**
Modifying just one line like following may prevent error.

```
class Weapon(object):
    def __init__(self,weaponName,weaponDamage):
        self.weaponName=weaponName
        self.weaponDamage=weaponDamage

class Character(object):
    def __init__(self,name,weaponName):
        self.name=name
        self.weapon=Weapon(weaponName, 1)#<-------modify like this...

class NPC(Character):
    def __init__(self,name,weaponName):
        super().__init__(name,weaponName)

class Friendly(NPC):
    def __init__(self,name,weaponName):
        super().__init__(name,weaponName)


sword=Weapon('sword',15)
guard=NPC('Bob','sword')

print(guard.weapon.weaponName)
print(guard.name)
```

Comment: By am I not providing the value in  sword=('sword',15)?

Comment: Sorry I can't see what you mean. I updated answer. See and try it. Also you should see @R Sahu answer.

Comment: OK, looks like I got it. With `self.weapon=Weapon(weaponName,1)` I would actually be creating a new instance of Weapon, right? But thats not what I wanted to do, I wanted to call the already existing instance of Weapon - sword. So instead it turns to `self.weapon=weapon.weaponName` and `self.damage=weapon.weaponDamage` with weapon as an __init__ argument and `guard=Friendly('Bob','sword)` ---> `guard=Friendly('Bob',sword)` just like @Mauricio said. Thanks for the answer though, it helped me realize what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize

```
self.weapon=Weapon(weaponName)
```

in your declaration for Character. You MUST provide the weaponDamage variable in your initialization or it will not work

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self,name,weaponName):
        self.name=name
        self.weapon=Weapon(weaponName)
```

Should become

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self,name,weaponName, weaponDamage):
        self.name=name
        self.weapon=Weapon(weaponName, weaponDamage) #This is where you should change it
```

And

```
guard=NPC('Bob','sword')
```

Should become

```
guard=NPC('Bob','sword',15)
```

That should work. Otherwise you would have to do some "if" statements in the Character initialization that set the value of weaponDamage to the type of weapon indicated by the weaponName.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing weapon name with Weapon object instance.
If you want to pass the Weapon instance to the Character, change your code to:

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self,name,weapon):
        self.name=name
        self.weapon=weapon
```

and

```
sword = Weapon('sword',15)
guard = NPC('Bob',sword)
```

note the sword without '.